# Difference between HttpContext.TraceIdentifier and Activity.Current.Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use a "trace id" in logs. Advice on the aspnet repo and here on SO is to get a traceid from `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier`.

But when the [framework](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/55738ff96b832439076e25584cfe0eb3bace9b01/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultProblemDetailsFactory.cs#L90) creates a `ProblemDetails` for a validation failure, it uses `Activity.Current?.Id`.

Examples:

```
var traceId1 = Activity.Current?.Id;        // OWZ4G27FO6UWH:00000003
var traceId2 = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier; // 00-2a8ee37903e657e3a95b41178dafc56e-91b02006afcf3133-00
```

I'm worried that my logs use one type of trace id, and the framework uses another - and when I find myself needing to analyse logs I'll have a problem.

How do these differ? Which should I use? Which type does the framework typically use?

### UPDATE

I asked on [the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39873) too, and they closed it without explanation. *If you have time, please open a new issue, and give us the link so we can upvote your issue.*

Answer (score 2):

The [HttpContext.TraceIdentifier Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.traceidentifier?view=aspnetcore-6.0): Gets or sets a unique identifier to represent **this request** in trace logs.

The [Activity.Current Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity.current?view=net-6.0): Gets or sets the current operation (Activity) for the **current thread**.

> var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? httpContext?.TraceIdentifier;

From the source code, we can see that it will use the Activity Id as the first choice, if the Activity Id is null, it will use the `httpContext?.TraceIdentifier`, you can also use this method to set the trace id.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the technical/literal difference between them. What I don't understand is whether the framework uses the one or the other more often, and why it uses one but recommends the other. in short: for a trace id to be useful, we should use the same type and format every time we log with a trace id. But that is not the case, hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea - that may hold water:

- Tasks where the aspnetcore is failing may or may not be associated with a HTTP request - but rather the `Activity.Current?.Id` is more relevant - what sub-action failed?
- Users of aspnetcore are often more concerned about which http request failed than which aspect of the underlying framework, hence the advice for `httpContext?.TraceIdentifier`.

Therefore, the appearance of a discrepancy may just be a different perspective from the core libraries and the custom server code as to what is the most appropriate ID.  So, most users should probably just follow the standard advice and use `httpContext?.TraceIdentifier`, or likely:

```
// Use http first to trace to client call, if available
// If not, fall back on the thread ID
var traceId = httpContext?.TraceIdentifier ?? Activity.Current?.Id;
```